# Vue.js - how to access data from child component in nested v-for iteration

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I'm trying to nest a v-for loop so that for every 4 results returned from my API, they will go collectively into a row.

```
 <div v-for="(item, index) in this.info.length/4" :key="item">
    <el-col v-for="thing in this.info" :key="thing">
      {{ thing }}
    </el-col>
 </div>
```

I'm aware that currently the nested v-for will print every item for the row, I still need to slice the results. However, when I try this code I get the following error:

`vue.esm.js?efeb:610 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined"`

For some reason I can't access this.info in the nested v-for loop, presumably because "this" is something else, perhaps the parent? Please can someone explain to me how this works and how I can access the data from a nested v-for child.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

you have 2 problems.

the simple one- 
there is no `this` in the template, so its undefined, and thats why you get the error. you should access `info` directly. (instead of `this.info`)

the second problem- your `v-for` seems to look like you wanted to iterate over an array. but what its actually doing is to iterate over all the numbers, from 0 to `info.length/4`. because if `info.length/4` is, say, 5, then your `v-for` evaluates to `v-for="(item, index) in 5"` and im not sure thats what you mean.